# How to create upload in each hexagon shape in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I create multi shape with canvas, but I want to upload a photo by clicking on each hexagon.

How to create with jquery?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const a = 2 * Math.PI / 6;
const r = 50;

// 1st
x = r;
y = r;
drawHexagon(x, y);

// 2nd
x = x + r + r * Math.cos(a);
y = y + r * Math.sin(a);
drawHexagon(x, y);

// 3rd
x = x + r + r * Math.cos(a);
y = y - r * Math.sin(a);
drawHexagon(x, y);

// 4th
x = x + r + r * Math.cos(a);
y = y + r * Math.sin(a);
drawHexagon(x, y);

function drawHexagon(x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(a * i), y + r * Math.sin(a * i));
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" />
```

Comment: Too many problems! First, how are you going to detect a click on a hexagon? Then, deal with uploads after that.

Comment: @ggorlen Hi, please check this site: https://modulari.com/en/hexagons.html

Comment: What am I supposed to conclude from that site? You seem to have a "write the code for me"/"where do I begin"/"can someone help me" question, which is off-topic. I'm suggesting that you [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) and try writing some code. If you get stuck, then ask for help. Otherwise, try a freelancer site if you want a full-featured implementation delivered to you. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen , I want to upload a photo by clicking on each shape, Only this...

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want, and I'm trying to explain to you that it's off-topic as too broad. To make it on topic, try writing some code, getting stuck, then asking a concrete technical question about that code, rather than simply dumping your requirements here and expecting someone to deliver the work in full. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Thanks.

Comment: From the above link: "Ask a programming question, not how to implement something" ...
"If you don't know the programming question to ask, at least break it down into as small a piece as possible, and still make it about programming, not the feature". You're asking about a feature, how to implement something, rather than a specific, answerable programming question.

Comment: 100% agree with @ggorlen this is very broad question, and to be honest it does not look you have attempted to solve your problem ... your code just draws polygons that is the easy stuff ... keep going do not get discouraged, the hard problems are the fun ones

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer the first part of your problem...
The comment from [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934522/how-to-create-upload-in-each-shape-in-canvas#comment132237560_74934522) is spot on, you have a complex situation, you must break it down into multiple questions and tackle each individually.

So how do we detect a mouse event over a particular shape in a canvas?
My recommendation use Path2D:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D
It comes with a handy function isPointInPath to detect if a point is in or path:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath

Sample code below, I'm using the mouse move event but you can use any other:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Hexagon {
  constructor(x, y, r, a) {
    this.path = new Path2D()
    for (var i = a; i < a+Math.PI*2; i+=Math.PI/3) {
      this.path.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(i), y + r * Math.sin(i));
    }
  }

  draw(evt) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    var x = evt.clientX - rect.left
    var y = evt.clientY - rect.top
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.isPointInPath(this.path, x, y) ? "red" : "green"
    ctx.fill(this.path)
  }
}

shapes = []
shapes.push(new Hexagon( 50, 50, 40, 0))
shapes.push(new Hexagon(125, 90, 45, 0.5))
shapes.push(new Hexagon(200, 50, 30, 0.8))
shapes.push(new Hexagon(275, 90, 53, 4.1))

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    shapes.forEach((s) => s.draw(evt))
  }
)
shapes.forEach((s) => s.draw({ clientX: 0, clientY: 0 }))
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="180" />
```

I hardcoded your constants to keep this example as small as possible
Also my `class Hexagon` takes the radius and angle as parameters that way we can have different Hexagons see: `constructor(x, y, r, a)`

Comment: hi, I need open upload manager after click in each Hexagon

Comment: @mySun yes you do ... what have you tried?